# ActionScript3 Error 5007

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe

I have this very simple program to do for a school project. I'm making a set of games based on the revolutionary war (irrelevant in this matter). This game involves an instance called player pushing a barrel off of a boat. Using my textbook, I have come up with code for a keyboard event that should move the player. The problem I get is that when I try to view my SWF, I get this 5007 error code and the player does not move. I'll post the code below. And I apologize in advance, my professor really just taught us basics and asked us to work with what we have. I think I can figure out the rest of my project if I can get this player to move.

```
package  
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;


public class Main_Character extends MovieClip {


    public function Main_Character() {

        init();
    }
    function init():void
    {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
        }
        public function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
            {
                player.x -= 10;
                }
            else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
            {
                player.x += 10;
                }
            else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
            {
                player.y += 10;
                }
                else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
            {
                player.y -= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: And what is the name of this `as` file?

Comment: the .as is Main_Character. I have changed it around a few times, I have another named main and all the code had been changed accordingly.

Comment: And what is your Root Class ?

Comment: I'm beginner at ActionScript 3.0, so I am not sure what my root class is. I am using 3.0 and according to Google there is no _root in AS3...where can i locate this?

Comment: Are you using Flash IDE? May be Flash CS5 or CS6 ?

Comment: I am using Flash CS6.

Comment: Great. Now open "File" - > "ActionScript settings" . What do you see in "Document Class" field?

Comment: The Document Class is "Main_Character".

Comment: Now press a "pen" button on the right side of the field , next after green "V" button. What's happening?

Comment: I clicked the "Edit class definition" button that has a pencil on it switched tabs to my open "Main_Character.as" file.

Comment: Hahaaaa dude wow my character is moving! Haha I can't believe it was something so simple.
Fixed the issue, looks like we forgot to save the files before testing.
Thank you!!

Comment: Great , i`ll post it like answer so you'll be able to "accept" it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `document class` name , and check if all `.as` files are saved.